# Does the pdf $f(x)=\frac{\Phi(x-c)-\Phi(x)}{c}$ have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $\Phi(x)$ be a Gaussian cdf.

Define a function 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\frac{\Phi(x-c)-\Phi(x)}{c}
\end{align}
for some fixed $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

It is not difficult to show that $f(x)$ is probability density function.

My question does this pdf have a name?

Comment: You should have $\frac{\Phi(x+c)-\Phi(x)}{c}$ or $\frac{\Phi(x)-\Phi(x-c)}{c}$; as it stands your quantity has the wrong sign. That, however, is nothing but the average of the Gaussian pdf on $[x,x+c]$, so this is some kind of locally averaged Gaussian. In fact you could call this a convolution of the Gaussian PDF with a uniform PDF on a certain interval of length $c$, thus this is a sum of a Gaussian and an independent uniform variable.

Comment: You should post that as an answer! @Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have $\frac{\Phi(x+c)−\Phi(x)}{c}$ or $\frac{\Phi(x)−\Phi(x−c)}{c}$; as it stands your quantity has the wrong sign. That, however, is nothing but the average of the Gaussian PDF on $[x,x+c]$ or $[x-c,x]$. So your PDF is the local average of the Gaussian PDF. In fact you could call this a convolution of the Gaussian PDF with a uniform PDF on a certain interval of length $c$. Thus you are looking at the PDF of the sum of a Gaussian and an independent uniform variable on the aforementioned interval.